# Aggregate two different events tables with a single query

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have a simple schema with a table for the `posts` and two tables to track `views` and `upvotes`:

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
    id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE views (
    post_id integer,
    value integer
);

CREATE TABLE upvotes (
    post_id integer,
    value integer
);
```

Please note that the tuples in `views` and `upvotes` represent a generic number of views and upvotes. I want to aggregate the posts, showing the **total amount of views and upvotes**.

I thought it'd be simple, but unfortunately I'm failing.

This is my query:

```
SELECT posts.title,
       SUM(views.value) AS views,
       SUM(upvotes.value) AS upvotes

FROM posts
    LEFT OUTER JOIN views ON (posts.id = views.post_id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN upvotes ON (posts.id = upvotes.post_id)

GROUP BY posts.id;
```

I understand why it's failing, but I really don't understand how to do it. If I need to run two different queries and aggregate the result on the application level, I'm fine with that. I just want to understand if it's possible with a single query

**I created a [sqlfiddle with my test case](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/ecb5d/2).**

PS: I manage to make it work using just a single generic table to track events, but I'd like to keep the table separated. [sqlfiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/f041e/12).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can safely calculate the values in a subquery. This will avoid you from summing up duplicate value leading you to an invalid result.

```
SELECT  p.id,
        p.title,
        COALESCE(v.totalView, 0) totalView,
        COALESCE(u.totalUpvote, 0) totalUpvote
FROM    posts p
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  post_id,
                    SUM(v.value) totalView
            FROM    views v
            GROUP   BY post_id
        ) v ON p.id = v.post_ID
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  post_id,
                    SUM(u.value) totalUpvote
            FROM    upvotes u
            GROUP   BY post_id
        ) u ON p.ID = u.post_ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/ecb5d/24)

Answer (score 1):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/ecb5d/44)

Do a JOIN between 2 separate selects

```
SELECT * FROM(SELECT posts.title,
       SUM(views.value) AS views
FROM posts
    LEFT OUTER JOIN views ON (posts.id = views.post_id)
GROUP BY posts.id)as x
JOIN(
SELECT posts.title,      
       SUM(upvotes.value) AS upvotes
FROM posts
    LEFT OUTER JOIN upvotes ON (posts.id = upvotes.post_id)
GROUP BY posts.id)as y on x.title=y.title
```